# is_category, is_single, is_page not working in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have  category named "magazine" and I create some article of this category. this is the link of my article `http://www.example.com/magazine/article-one/` I want to check in function.php if I'm in this category or not, for that I use `if(is_category('magazine')){die('I am in magazine category');}` but I got nothing. I tried by using `is_single` and `is_page` but all this function not working.

Comment: Can you show the code you use in functions.php? Did you put it in a function? Attach it to a hook?

Comment: So, what exactly is "getting nothing"? Seeing a white page (might be a parser error)? Result as usual (might be the wrong theme active)? Anything else? This is necessary to provide any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes these functions will not work directly in functions.php , for that you need to use them like the following ,

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_archive_posts' ,5);
function limit_archive_posts($query){
    if ($query->is_category) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }
    if($query->is_single == 1){
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

or use them in the wp_enqueue_scripts , wp_head, wp_footer filters.

Comment: Let us know how did you proceed  by adding the code you tried

Comment: Hi, I waw  using the code above but instead of `if ($query->is_category)`  I was using `if ('magazine' == $query->query_vars['category_name'])` and it worked now.

Answer (score 1):

You can not these functions in function.php otherwise they will have no mean. `is_category` check category. It will get category on taxonomy page query.

you can either use this action to do your work

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_archive_posts' ,5);
function limit_archive_posts($query){
    if ('magazine' === $query->is_category) {

     }
    if(1 === $query->is_single){

    }
    return $query;
}
```

you can put your functions logic in theme `functions.php` 
and you can use this condition on `taxonomy.php` or `archive.php`
to render your appropriate logic based on condition

```
if(is_category('magazine')){
    call_my_category_work_function();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why I have to do this code `if(is_category('magazine')){
    call_my_category_work_function();
}`  in taxonomy.php ?. I think the filter `pre_get_posts` is worked.

Comment: If someone is beginner and not understand `actions` and `filters` well
these can be done through this way.

it much simpler to add login part in functions.php and the template-specific work in template.

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

```
 $category_object=get_queried_object();
 $category_term_id = $category_object->term_id;
 if($category_term_id == "your magazine term_id")       
 {
    echo 'I am in magazine category';   
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thank u for your replay, but `category_object` return empty for me!!

Comment: please share your url.

Comment: my url look like : `http://demo.muretprestige.com/magazine/magazine-mur-prestige-n1/`

Comment: "magazine" is your page slug and also category "magazine" right?
if "Yes" Then please change your page slug like "magazine-page".
Because both are conflict